# Histogram in % in Kibana

Tags: histogram, percentage, kibana

I'd like to create a percentage histogram visualization in Kibana.
Each document has a 'DurationInSeconds'  field and I can create a histogram with a bucket size (e.g. 10, [0,9], [10,19], [20,29], ...) and count (number of documents when the duration is within one bucket ). 
But, I'd like to have this histogram in Percentage on Y-axis. 
I think using JSON Input it might be possible, but don't know how to do this. 
Is it possible to create percentage histogram?

Thanks